# Creating vector of sslstream

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am trying to create a vector of sslstreams using the following code

```
std::vector<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> vecStreams;
```

I am receiving two errors

template argument 1 is invalid
template argument 2 is invalid

I am just a beginner so go easy on me if this is a simple problem. Thanks.

Comment: Just an information for further questions: It was quite easy to solve this time, but next time please include the *full* error message (something being invalid usually doesn't help too much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `>` at the end:

```
std::vector<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> > vecStreams;
```